# Sending metrics from kafka to grafana

Tags: apache-kafka, grafana, metrics

I have a use case in which metrics will be written to kafka topics and from there I have to send these metrics to a grafana collection point.

Can it be done without a datasource?

Any idea how it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

You need to store your metrics somewhere and then visualize it. If you want to use Grafana, you can store metric data from Kafka to Elasticsearch via connectors. I think you can also store them in InfluxDB, Graphite, and Prometheus. You can use data source plugins that Grafana provides.

Also using Kibana is a good option. Kibana is like Graphana.  Elasticsearch and Kibana are part of Elastic Stack.

Refer to the below pics.

## 1 :

[image]

## 2 :

[image]

Comment: Big advantage of Grafana over Kibana is , its not limited to just ES as datasource. Now coming to the main Q :  yes you could leverage Kafka as a datasource and vizualize data in grafana .  see this : https://www.confluent.io/blog/analytics-with-apache-kafka-and-rockset/

Answer (score 1):

I found this open source code that is basically a kafka plugin for Grafana.

https://github.com/zylklab/lorca

You can either use it straightaway or get inspired to write your own Grafana plugin.